# Binding data returned from join to grid using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

So, I've been dabbling in entity framework now n then for 2 days now and I just encountered a problem which not even google could solve for me...

I have an stored procedure, in which I'm extracting data from 2 tables using join and iam trying to bind this data  to gridview.

I have successfully bound data to gridview using following methods..

```
gv_testef.DataSource=db.contacts;//for whole table

gv_testef.DataSource = db.contacts.Where(p => p.id == 2); //for a few records..
```

and I tried this now..

```
gv_testef.DataSource = db.get_details();//get_details is the stored procedure in question
```

Query is:

```
   SELECT c.fname,c.lname, a.address,a.city,a.state,a.pincode, c.phone from contact c
   JOIN address_details a on c.id=a.id
```

But it isnt working ..

Kindly help in this regard.

Comment: what's get_details() ? 

try

 var ds = db.get_details();
 gv_testef.DataSource = ds ;

and check what ds is , and check it's result set.

Comment: updated the question......and ds=-1

Comment: so if get_details() returned -1  how could that be used as a datasource 

i'm guessing it returns -1 for no result set.

Comment: but i tried the query separately(outside sp) and its returning 2 rows...but when i run the sp its returning -1.....ITS A SIMPLE JOIN QUERY

Comment: see question for query

Comment: run this and tell me the result 

DECLARE 

    SELECT c.fname,c.lname, a.address,a.city,a.state,a.pincode, c.phone from contact c
   INNER JOIN address_details a on c.id=a.id

Comment: c.id = a.id    are you sure that seems really odd ...
shouldn't it be c.id = a.C_id  ?

Comment: Thx for the help dude...Figured it out...During function import had to specify return type as "COMPLEX"..